# saving image to internal memory and would appear in the gallery

Tags: android

I have search much of questions related to my question..Is there anyway to store an image in internal memory and it should appear in the gallery as well?

Comment: If u r Interested to save image into sdcard then i will give you code for that.

Comment: thanks, but i already have set a function to save the image in the sdcard using this..

[getExternalStoragePublicDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

i want to know if i can save an image internally then the image would appear in the gallery

Answer (score 2):

It's totally possible, I've done this before.

Before you are saving an image to the internal memory(or called app folder, etc.), you'd better set `Context.MODE_WORLDREADABLE`. Although I set MODE_PRIVATE and can be read from gallery after I ran MediaScanner in my case, I recommend you set MODE_PRIVATE for the safety concern.

After you've saved your image to the internal memory, you can call MediaScanner like this:

```
// call media scanner to refresh gallery
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{filePath}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    
        Log.i("MediaScanner", "Scanned " + path + ":");
        Log.i("MediaScanner", "-> uri=" + uri);
    }
});
```

Copy/Paste the code above should work. Then your image will appear to the gallery.

Reference of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE)

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your internal memory as a directory and write your file on it. Sample code coulde be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135927/copy-image-to-internal-memory). Loading image from memory is the same with reading binary image file from directory. Then you convert the file you have read to Bitmap using [decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) and display on your gallery.

This is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307274/android-save-image-from-internet-to-internal-external-storage-and-display-it) of saving image and display on screen (but this one is on webview instead of gallery).

Comment: thank you for the reply, i am using this code to save it internally in the

Comment: thank you for the reply, i was able to save the image internally in the "data/data/com.example/files" directory..

I wanted it to be scanned so that it would appear in the phone gallery..I know images saved internally are private to your app. I did try scanning the image in the "data/data/com.example/files" directory using "MediaScannerConnection.scanFile".

I am using an emulator without an sdcard attach, so i rather get exceptions or errors because the phone would create a thumb in gallery(which i think needs an external storage - sdcard to store it)..

Comment: I wanted to save the image internally for android phones without an sdcard mounted, where users are prompt to save the image and they can view the image in the gallery. 
I am also left wandering where camera taken pics are save in phones without sdcard.